# I tried assigning the "setInterval" function in javaScript to a variable so that I can terminate the function and restart it back again as needed

Tags: javascript

My goal was to use the "setInterval()" function to change the selected radio button once every 5 seconds.
but the user also has the ability to manually select the label of the linked radio button(linking the labeling of the radio button is done within the HTML)
and if the user selects a linked label manually; the "setInterval()" function should select the next radio and should continue.

```
let radios = document.getElementsByClassName("manualRadio");
let repeater;

function startRepeating(current){

    repeater = setInterval(function(current){

    document.getElementById("radio" + current).checked = true;
    current++;
      if(current > 4){
        current = 1;
      }
}, 5000);
}

startRepeating(1);

for (let i = 0; i < radios.length; i++){
    radios[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
       let currentClicked = this.getAttribute("id").slice(10, 11);
       clearInterval(repeater);
        startRepeating(currentClicked);
        
        
    });

}
```

I tired debugging the code and found that function does not assigned to the repeater variable as intended (As shown in the first image (link-1))
[text](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NWaTofJQvetcQ8NL2bf92HO3MVY7_j-q/view?usp=sharing)

and the program crashed in the next line as shown in the second image (link-2)
[text](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VRCBe9fPz9fSuODJOdRMROLadHLWBOl6/view?usp=drive_link)

Comment: can you also share the html ?

Comment: currentClicked is undefined so your problem is the currentClicked assignment. Please dont link external images unless you want to be downvoted and told not to link exten images (:

Comment: @danielRICADO `let currentClicked = ...` looks defined to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line `setInterval(function(current){`. `current` is undefined because inner `current` have shadowed outer `current`. In you code you can skip the `current` defined as parameter of the callback function, as I presume you are referring the `current` which is defined as parameter of the `startRepeating` function.

```js
let radios = document.getElementsByClassName("manualRadio");
let repeater;

function startRepeating(current) {

  repeater = setInterval(function() { //removed current from here
    console.log(current)
    document.getElementById("radio" + current).checked = true;
    current++;
    if (current > 4) {
      current = 1;
    }
  }, 5000);
}

startRepeating(1);

for (let i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
  radios[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    let currentClicked = this.getAttribute("id"); //.slice(10, 11);
    clearInterval(repeater);
    startRepeating(currentClicked);


  });

}
```

```html
<label for='radio1'>1</label>
<input type='radio' id='radio1'>
<label for='radio2'>2</label>
<input type='radio' id='radio2'>
<label for='radio3'>3</label>
<input type='radio' id='radio3'>
<label for='radio4'>4</label>
<input type='radio' id='radio4'>
<label for='radio5'>5</label>
<input type='radio' id='radio5'>
```

If you want to pass a parameter to the callback function of the `setTimeout` you need to use `setTimeout` in this way

`setTimeout(functionRef, delay, param1)`. Then the `param1` will be passed to the callback function of the setTimeout

```js
let radios = document.getElementsByClassName("manualRadio");
let repeater;

function startRepeating(current) {

  repeater = setInterval(function(current) {
    console.log(current)
    document.getElementById("radio" + current).checked = true;
    current++;
    if (current > 4) {
      current = 1;
    }
  }, 5000, current); // passed the current param
}

startRepeating(1);

for (let i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
  radios[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    let currentClicked = this.getAttribute("id"); //.slice(10, 11);
    clearInterval(repeater);
    startRepeating(currentClicked);


  });

}
```

```html
<label for='radio1'>1</label>
<input type='radio' id='radio1'>
<label for='radio2'>2</label>
<input type='radio' id='radio2'>
<label for='radio3'>3</label>
<input type='radio' id='radio3'>
<label for='radio4'>4</label>
<input type='radio' id='radio4'>
<label for='radio5'>5</label>
<input type='radio' id='radio5'>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for helping
Now everything is running as smoothly as I wanted
Apart from just being able to fix my code I also was able to learn
a lot from your answer.
once again thanks very much for helping me.
good luck!!!

Answer (score 0):

You should post text, not images, and include error messages. I can't see any in the images. Also, post (minimal) runnable code, even if it crashes (but say so if it does) so include appropriate (minimal) HTML. Often creating the sample will lead you to find the issue.

If I understand what you want to do correctly, you can make this much simpler by just selecting the next radio at the end of each interval.

If the user intervenes, restart the timer so it starts again from the user–selected radio.

E.g.

```js
// Check next radio button
// radios is a collection of radio buttons
function setChecked(radios) {
//  let radios = document.querySelector('form').foo;
  let checkedIdx = [...radios].findIndex(el => el.checked);

  // If none checked, check first
  if (checkedIdx < 0) {
    radios[0].checked = true;

    // Otherwise, check next
  } else {
    radios[(checkedIdx + 1) % radios.length].checked = true;
  }
}


// Add listeners
(function() {
  let lag = 2000;
  let radios = document.querySelector('form').foo;

  radios.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click',
    () => {
      clearInterval(timerID);
      timerID = setInterval(() => setChecked(radios), lag);
    })
  );

  // Initialise the timer
  let timerID = setInterval(() => setChecked(radios), lag);
})()
```

```css
label {
  padding: 0 5px 0 20px;
  border: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <!-- Default selected radio --> 
  <label>1<input type='radio' name='foo' class='manualRadio' checked></label>
  <label>2<input type='radio' name='foo' class='manualRadio'></label>
  <label>3<input type='radio' name='foo' class='manualRadio'></label>
  <label>4<input type='radio' name='foo' class='manualRadio'></label>
  <label>5<input type='radio' name='foo' class='manualRadio'></label>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for you feedback
and for helping me with the task...
good luck !!!